# Adding things to a python Class

Tags: python, class

I need to find a way to add a number to the `SchoolMember` class but every time I try, I get an error. Here is the code:

```
class SchoolMember:
    # Represents any school member.
    def __init__(self, name, age, number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number= number
        print ('(Initialized SchoolMember: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        '''Tell my details.'''
        print ('Name:"{}" Age:"{}" Number:"{}"'.format(self.name, self.age,self.number),)

class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    # Represents a teacher.
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary,number):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.salary = salary
        print ('(Initialized Teacher: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print ('Salary: "{:d}"'.format(self.salary))

class Student(SchoolMember):
    # Represents a student.
    def __init__(self, name, age, marks,number):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
        self.marks = marks
        print ('(Initialized Student: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print ('Marks: "{:d}"'.format(self.marks))
t = Teacher('Mr. Smith', 32, 50000, 9056789056)
s = Student('Jagroop', 15, 82, 9056761212)
# prints a blank line
print()
members = [t, s]
for member in members:
    # Works for both Teachers and Students
    member.tell()
```

I even added the numbers down at the bottom but the program keeps telling me that it doesn't have the propsition or something.

I would really appreciate help as my knowledge on python classes is really low, Thank you!!

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
File "C:/Users/hi/Desktop/class1.py", line 31, 
in <module> t = Teacher('Mr. Smith', 32, 50000, 9056789056) 
File "C:/Users/hi/Desktop/class1.py", line 15, 
in init SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age) 
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number' >>>
```

Comment: Well, im trying to add a phone number to the school memberclass th name and age already work, the error that im getting is this:

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/hi/Desktop/class1.py", line 31, in <module>
    t = Teacher('Mr. Smith', 32, 50000, 9056789056)
  File "C:/Users/hi/Desktop/class1.py", line 15, in __init__
    SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'number'
>>>

Comment: You should be using `super()` to call the `__init__()` method of the parent class. [Read the docs here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age)
```

Change it to:

```
SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age, number)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class SchoolMember:
    #Represents any school member.
    def __init__(self, name, age, number):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.number= number
        print ('(Initialized SchoolMember: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        '''Tell my details.'''
        print ('Name:"{}" Age:"{}" Number:"{}"'.format(self.name, self.age,self.number),)

class Teacher(SchoolMember):
    #Represents a teacher.
    def __init__(self, name, age, salary, number):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age, number)
        self.salary = salary
        print ('(Initialized Teacher: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print ('Salary: "{:d}"'.format(self.salary))

class Student(SchoolMember):
    #Represents a student.
    def __init__(self, name, age, marks, number):
        SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age, number)
        self.marks = marks
        print ('(Initialized Student: {})'.format(self.name))
    def tell(self):
        SchoolMember.tell(self)
        print ('Marks: "{:d}"'.format(self.marks))

t = Teacher('Mr. Smith', 32, 50000, 9056789056)
s = Student('Jagroop', 15, 82, 9056761212)
# prints a blank line
print()
members = [t, s]
for member in members:
    # Works for both Teachers and Students
    member.tell()
```

The error you're getting is there because you didn't update your calls to instantiation of parent class to:

```
SchoolMember.__init__(self, name, age, number)
```

in both the Student and Teacher classes.